# how to set property chrome driver in mac os

Tags: java, macos, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am working with win os and using selenium. other workers use mac.
The problem is that every one is with different chrome driver version and different os.
we want that the chrome driver will not be part of the project at all (it is running in remote ant the chrome driver is located their).
For windows it is very very easy

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
```

how can I perform this in mac OS (please very basic hard coded, we do not want it as part of the project at all, do not want to install chromdriver,just to use this command in mac OS, so when we pull from master each person can mark as comment the unnecessary path )

I just want to read the chrome driver in mac os from the download folder or where it is located when downloading at mac, please the simple solution
regards

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way in mac that I use is homebrew

If you don't have homebrew installed, refer this document

https://brew.sh/

Once, home brew is installed use the following command  to install chormedriver, moving forward you will not have to set properties to the executable

brew tap homebrew/cask && brew cask install chromedriver